# Problems Setting Up Testacular With Jasmine and Angular

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm trying to set up a unit testing environment for my project and I'm having some problems. I'm trying to use Testacular with Jasmine for testing my AngularJS code.

I have a module `Services` which has a factory method called KeepAlive. Here is its set up.

```
angular.module('services', []).factory('KeepAlive', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope){
    //My Code
}]);
```

This module is attached to a module called `MainModule`. Here is its code.

```
angular.module('MainModule', ['filters', 'services', 'directives', 'ui'])
.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider){
    //My Code
}]).run(['$rootScope', '$timeout', '$routeParams', 'KeepAlive', function($rootScope, $timeout, $routeParams, KeepAlive){
    //My Code
}]);
```

So Now I want to add this code for my tests. So here is my testacular file set up.

```
     JASMINE,
     JASMINE_ADAPTER,
     'assets/lib/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.js',
     'assets/lib/angular/angular.js',
     'assets/lib/angular/angular-ui.js',
     'jsTests/MockingLib/angular-mocks.js',
     'assets/scripts/modules/Admin.js',
     'assets/scripts/modules/MainModule.js',
     'assets/scripts/services/KeepAlive.js',
     'assets/scripts/services/Admin.js',
     'assets/scripts/filters.js',
     'assets/scripts/directives.js',
     'assets/scripts/controllers/admin/*.js',
```

Now this is throwing a error in my testacular console. Here is the error that I'm getting.

```
Error: Unknown provider: KeepAliveProvider <- KeepAlive
     at Error (<anonymous>)
     at d:/Work/Workspace/TalentNetwork/assets/lib/angular/angular.js:2627:8
     at Object.getService [as get] (d:/Work/Workspace/TalentNetwork/assets/lib/angular/angular.js:2755:32)
     at d:/Work/Workspace/TalentNetwork/assets/lib/angular/angular.js:2632:38
     at getService (d:/Work/Workspace/TalentNetwork/assets/lib/angular/angular.js:2755:32)
     at Object.invoke (d:/Work/Workspace/TalentNetwork/assets/lib/angular/angular.js:2773:6)
     at d:/Work/Workspace/TalentNetwork/assets/lib/angular/angular.js:2637:71
     at Array.forEach (native)
     at forEach (d:/Work/Workspace/TalentNetwork/assets/lib/angular/angular.js:110:11)
     at Object.createInjector [as injector] (d:/Work/Workspace/TalentNetwork/assets/lib/angular/angular.js:2637:3)
```

Here is my Jasmine Test case.

```
beforeEach(function () {
    admin = module("MainModule");
    module("services");
});
```

What I'm I missing? I'm new to testacular. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure you are calling `module('services')` in a `beforeEach` block in your tests.

Comment: BTW, if I remove KeepAlive from my run method and also from my file list, it executes all my test cases

Comment: I'm pretty sure @Vojta and I are are right - the module's not getting loaded. Is your code on Github?

Comment: Thanks Josh I'd misplaced my files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error says that somebody asked for a service called "KeepAlive" but the injector does not know how to create it (there is no provider for it).

That means, you probably didn't load the module.

When you bootstrap your app on production, you give it `ng-app="something"`, which tells Angular which module to load. In the same way, you need to specify which modules you wanna load during testing.

**This should solve your problem:**

```
beforeEach(module('services'));
```

Comment: Hi @Vojta. Thanks for the reply. I have loaded my module. I have included `module("MainModule");` in my beforeEach. I also tried adding what you told me to. It didnt work. What I'm I missing?

Comment: Go to http://localhost:9876/debug.html and check the console if there are some other errors. This has nothing to do with Testacular.

Comment: Sorry for the trouble @Vojta. I had not ordered my files properly. Thanks a ton for your help